# I am trying to save picture to PictureAPIView

Tags: image, post, django-rest-framework

MODELS.py

```
class MyPicture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=join_path('pictures'))
```

SERIALIZERS.PY

```
class MyPictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    picture = serializers.ImageField(required=True, use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MyPicture
        fields = ['id', 'picture']
```

VIEWS.PY

```
class MyPictureAPI(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FormParser, FileUploadParser)
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.FILES)
        serializer = MyPictureSerializer(data=request.FILES)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

if I print(request.FILES) ,
it is {'file': <InMemoryUploadedFile: cloud_vazifa_01.png (multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------563292059865884360215980)>}

here key is 'file' but i have saved it to model and serializer as 'picture'

so serilizer is invalid
help me to save picture to models

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyLae.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `FileField`, not `ImageField`.

```
class MyPictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    picture = serializers.FileField(
        max_length = 10000000,
        allow_empty_file = False
        use_url = False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyPicture
        fields = ['id', 'picture']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        image = validated_data.pop('picture')
        return MyPicture.objects.create(picture = image)
```

In `MyPictureAPI`,

```
class MyPictureAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = MyPictureSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked.
what about posting file?